# Strapi customization workflow and CI/CD

Tags: git, strapi

Is there documentation somewhere on how to make changes (adding content type locally) and store this in a git repo and ci/cd to hosted server? let us say I want 2 envs - dev and prod, want to make changes on my machine and push to git ,ci/cd will kick-in and deploy to dev/prod.

Answer (score -1):

I use Jenkins to make what you are looking for.

I think this article can be a good starting point:

https://medium.com/@mosheezderman/how-to-set-up-ci-cd-pipeline-for-a-node-js-app-with-jenkins-c51581cc783c

Comment: I know how to setupo ci/cd , my qurestion was more on strapi side, what is the best practice for having multiple envs?

Comment: The config will be different (you can see how to edit for each ENV here: https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/configurations.html#server